# Cordova : cordova run android execute well but the code didn't get the new changes

Tags: cordova

i have `cordova` app i changed the code and run `cordova run android` execute well app launch on device but the code changes are not, still the same code with no changes.

Comment: Hehe :p have you tried to restart the android device and your computer?

Comment: What i do when i got theses kinds of problems. I remove the platform and i add them again ;)

Comment: i did removed the platfrom and add it again still same problem.

Answer (score 0):

What code have you change?
If it is your HTML/CSS/JS code, have you change it in yourApp/www folder or in yourApp/platforms/android/assets/www folder?
the former is where you should change and the latter is a generated folder (so every time a build command is ran, it get overridden by yourApp/www content).
For android code, normally, you don't have this kind of issue!